# How to handle multiple targets in XCode using swift language?

Tags: xcode

I have created two targets in XCode but I am using swift. 
Can anybody know please how to handle multiple targets using swift? As we were doing in Objective-C as given in below example.

```
#if defined(TARGET_LITE)

      NSLog("Lite version");

 #else

      NSLog("Original version");

 #endif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could of cause use preprocessor statements like `#if` in Swift but I think you need to define the target-variables by yourself. I am using it as follows:

*Build Settings* -> *Swift Compiler Flags* -> *Other Swift Flags* 
Set a variable `-D LITE` in your lite-target configuration

In your code you could use it like this:

```
#if LITE
   // do something
#else
  // do something else
#endif
```

Comment: @Daniel, I am using xcode 7, For me macros are not working.

Answer (score 4):

Under the target's *Build Settings* search for "flags" and add `-D TARGET_LITE` to *Swift Compiler - Custom Flags* > *Other Swift Flags*:

[image]

Observe how it's getting passed to the compiler by looking in the build log (hard to read, sorry):

[image]