# Swift: Multiple targets handling: macros not working

Tags: ios, xcode, macros, targets

from the reference [How to handle multiple targets in XCode using swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449892/how-to-handle-multiple-targets-in-xcode-using-swift-language) and https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/

I have created three targets, each target having different bundle ids and app icons. I have also added different flag to the "Other swift flags" - > Custom swift flag section

like

for first target I added **"-DGOLD"** , 
for second target I added **"-DSILVER"** and for
third target I added **"-DPLATINUM"**.

In the AppDelegate I wrote a code

```
#if GOLD
print ("Gold")
#elseif SILVER
print ("Silver")
#else
print ("Platinum")
#endif
```

FYI, `I am using Xcode 8.3`

I tried to run the first target, I always getting "Platinum". Please provide me how to get the flags correctly

Comment: Are you looking for `#ifdef` instead?

Comment: @Larme '#ifdef' is a objective c syntax i guess..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `#endif` after the block but I'm not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24003291/2773311)

Answer (score 2):

I am working with Xcode 9.
I am having same problem and looked for an answer for a few hours and finally found the solution.
At each Target, Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags, I added the wanted flag like this:

Target1 -> -DTARGET1

Target2 -> -DTARGET2

Then in my code used:

```
#if TARGET1
//
#elseif TARGET2
//
#endif
```