# Set swift macros from cmake

Tags: swift, xcode, cmake

I have a swift project which uses macros for conditional compilation.

How to set macro:
Go to Target -> BuildSettings -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Active Compilation Conditions and add your macro (Ex: sample macro - ELDIABLO in this case).

[image]

Then the following,

```
#if ELDIABLO
NSLog("ELDIABLO macro detected!")
#else 
NSLog("ELDIABLO macro not detected!")
#endif
```

...produces the desired output.

```
ELDIABLO macro detected!
```

Now, how do I achieve this through cmake?

When I do the following,

```
set(CMAKE_Swift_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Swift_FLAGS} ELDIABLO")
```

the macro gets added to Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Other Swift Flags (shown in the above image).
But it must be added in Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Active Compilation Conditions ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484715/swift-multiple-targets-handling-macros-not-working) why) else, it will not get detected in swift files.

How can I set swift macros in Active Compilation Conditions through cmake?